# Python write nested loops with list comprehension for mult-variable function output

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have the following loop in Python 2.7.

```
pressure = []; cycle_flow = []; gauge_val = []
for element in readout_list:
    if element.endswith('.dat'):
        v1_2_3 = extract_sensor_values(element)
        pressure.append(v1_2_3[0])
        cycle_flow.append(v1_2_3[1])
        gauge_val.append(v1_2_3[2])
```

I am trying to write this as a list comprehension in one line. If the function `extract_sensor()` only returned one variable then I could easily use this list comprehension:

```
v1_2_3=[extract_sensor_values(element) for element in readout_list if element.endswith('.dat')]
```

However, I am not sure how to get three variables simultaneously from the function, using list comprehension. This seems simple when using multiple lines, but when I try to put it on one line it doesn't work.

Is it possible to return multiple function values in a list comprehension?

Comment: Also note that "fewer lines of code" is not a metric to be aimed for blindly.  While it's true that sometimes you can use a language's expressiveness to write complex things in fewer lines, it's _more_ common that people jam too much on a single line which leads to a nearly incomprehensible jumble of sadness.

Comment: I agree. We'll see below how this turns out. It may well be, in this specific case, that a one-liner isn't actually possible without making it difficult to easily read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't the sort of task that list-comprehensions were created to address.  Each list comprehension in your code should produce exactly 1 list.

One thing you *could* do is use a list-comprehension to get the `pressure`, `cycle_flow` and `guage_val` triples and then use `zip` to "transpose" the result...

```
triples = [extract_sensor_values(element)
           for element in readout_list if element.endswith('.dat')]
pressure, cycle_flow, guage_val = zip(*triples)
```

A word of caution however -- This will leave you with `tuple` for the `pressure`, `cycle_flow` and `guage_val` variables (instead of `list` as was in your original code).

Comment: Correct and then I could just finish it with `for x in [pressure, cycle_flow, guage_val]: list(x)` - this gives me lists for all 3 variables. This is not a one-liner, but involves 2 lines - but it works for me. Why is list comprehension not appropriate here?

Comment: @WR -- Because list comprehensions are meant as simple transforms.  It transforms an input iterable into an output list.  It isn't designed to transform an input iterable into an arbitrary number of output lists.  I would guess that the fundamental problem is that nobody's thought of a syntax that would allow that to be done clearly.  It's likely that no syntax for doing it _clearly_ exists, but I suppose it's also possible that nobody has thought the need pressing enough to spend their time thinking about it (yet).